# I am hanafi but i want to do Rafa yadain in salat... Can i do?

Tags: salat, sunnah, hanafi

Aslamwalekum, I am Sunni Hanafi and hanafi don't do raful yadain in Salat. But i see that is in hadeesh that rasool allah(s.a.w) was doing raful yadain.an i want to do Raful Yadain in Hanafi Madhab.

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to ask. The Hanafis claim that the Prophet ﷺ abandoned the practice so according to them it is abrogated and against the sunnah to do so. If you find the opposing evidence to be stronger you can act on it, although that would not be in accordance to the Hanafi madhab.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing hindering you to do so. Especially as you came across that it is sunnah and if you are rather sure of its authenticity.

Be aware that even if the Hanafi maddhab doesn't follow this sunnah this doesn't mean that the Hanafi scholars have not discussed the hadith its authenticity and validity, so they certainly have reasons for not following it. That's why for example imam Malik has quoted ahadith in his al-Muwatta', but added statements about whether or not this sunnah is to follow or there's a stronger view in his madhhab. Ibn al-Majushoon commented it we have quoted it to show that we rejected it by knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Some Hanafis do rafa’yadan!

But who said you have to follow on school of thought! The only one to be followed alone is our Prophet Sallallaahualaihiwasallam صلى الله عليه وسلم

Read this excellent book that would explain everything:

http://www.islamnd.org/Events/Prophet_Prayer2.pdf

Answer (score -1):

That's great, I used to be Hanafi as my family belongs to it. but certainly I started exploring things and it's authenticity and I found that Doing Rafa yadin hadiths are much stronger than the one's that show not to do it.

follow this article for more detailed view
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/21439/raising-the-hands-during-prayer

Answer (score -1):

Hanafi fiqa claim that our Prophet abandoned Rafa’Yadan but there is NOT a single Hadith showing abandon Rafa’yadin. There are hundreds of Hadiths including a separate chapter  Juz Rafa’yadin in Bukhari proving our Prophet did Rafa’yadin.

There is one weak (unproven) Hadith they refer showing Namaz without Rafa’yadin but it doesn’t say it was abandoned. There is an evidence of Rafa’yadin from Hazarat Abu baker, Umer, Ali, Imam Bukhari and so on and even Hazarat Abdul Qadir Jilani did Rafa’yadin. It is ironic that followers of Abdul Qadir Jilani don’t do it.

You can pray Nimaz without it, I understand fully but saying something without  proof is NOT right. (Allah know the best)